# Subset a list (choose matching values for all components)

Tags: r, list

I try to read out certain elements from a list in a way, thats equivalent to `df[, c(1,4,5)]` in a `data.frame`.

```
> obj <- list(c(1:5), c(1:5))
> obj
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Im looking for a result like this

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 4 5
```

I have been experimenting with `[]`, `[[]]` and `[[]][]` but thats assessing the list componentwise.
I've also been trying `lapply(obj, c(1,4,5))` and looking at `match()`.

I'm not quite there yet, help would be appreciated.

Thx!

Comment: You're almost there. `lapply(obj, '[', c(1, 4, 5))`.  But I'm not sure how you got your second list subset of `[1] 1 3 4`.

Comment: Thank you Justin, it*s working and i corrected my type up above. What does '[' do exactly? It isn't a function, is it?

Comment: It sure is!  Take a look at `?"["`.

Answer (score 2):

You should call lapply with a function which is run on every list entry:

```
obj <- list(c(1:5), c(1:5))
lapply(obj, function(x) x[c(1, 4, 5)])
#[[1]]
[1] 1 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

EDi has a great answer, but you can do it by passing the `[` function to `lapply` plus additional arguments:

```
lapply(obj, '[', c(1, 4, 5))
```

You can access this and the other "weird" functions in R by quoting them:

```
?"["
```